# What is best strategy to verify text of multiple elements without adding a ton of locators in a selenium framework?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation

I want to automate a test using selenium java in which I need to check whether a specific text is NOT present on the entire page.

The page has many elements where this text may be present. In general, if it were a few elements, I could resolve this via standard `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//somepath")).getText()`. But, I want to write an efficient test that doesn't have tons of locators just for this test.

Comment: It is a general question about strategy and not about getting stuck on some code. That is why I didn't add the code.

Comment: This is just a general question. I've already shared the code above in my question that I have already tried. I'm just asking better strategy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use XPATH selector `'//*[contains(text(), "YOUR_TEXT")]` to find a text that you need.

Example of the code on Python:

```
def find_text_on_the_page(text):
    selector = '//*[contains(text(), "{}")]'.format(text)
    elements = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(selector)
    assert len(elements), 'The text is not on the page'
```

Hope, this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to locate it via xPath selector, but I would not recommend test like that.

Surely You know where to look for some test? At least a part of web page.

Here is code sample how to achieve this:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'" + text + "')]"));
Assert.assertTrue("Text not found!", list.size() > 0);
```

or

```
String bodyText = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body")).getText();
Assert.assertTrue(bodyText.contains(text));
```

or in method:

```
public boolean isTextOnPagePresent(String text) {
    WebElement body = driver.findElement(By.tagName("body"));
    String bodyText = body.getText();
    return bodyText.contains(text);
}
```

Hope this helps, but as I mentioned try defining a smaller scope for testing.